# Compare two different csv with key column in python

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 csv named abc.csv and xyz.csv. I can able to achieve in Excel using VLOOKUP. Would like to do in python.

**abc.csv**

```
"uid","isDisabled"
"user.0","active"
"user.1","Disabled"
"user.2","active"
"user.3","Disabled"
"user.4","active"
"user.5","Disabled"
"user.6","active"
"user.8","active"
```

**xyz.csv**

```
"uid","status"
"user.0","active"
"user.1","active"
"user.2","active"
"user.5","active"
"user.7","active"
```

Looking for result like.

**output.csv**

```
"uid","status","abc_status"
"user.0","active","NOCHANGE"
"user.1","active","Disabled in ABC"
"user.2","active","NOCHANGE"
"user.5","active","Disabled in ABC"
"user.7","active","Does not exist in ABC"
```

Is this achievable ?

I tried in Excel.  Not in python.

Comment: is it achievable? -  yes.  read the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: You are able to do it both with pandas and the built-in CSV module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import package:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Read the CSV files:

```
abc_df = pd.read_csv("abc.csv")
xyz_df = pd.read_csv("xyz.csv")
```

Merge these dataframes based on `uid`:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(xyz_df, abc_df, on="uid", how="left")
```

Define a function to check the status:

```
def status(row):
    if pd.isna(row["isDisabled"]):
        return "Does not exist in ABC"
    elif row["status"] == row["isDisabled"]:
        return "NOCHANGE"
    else:
        return "Disabled in ABC"
```

Apply the `status()` function to each row of the `merged_df`:

```
merged_df["abc_status"] = merged_df.apply(status, axis=1)
```

Output dataframe:

```
output_df = merged_df[["uid", "status", "abc_status"]]
```

Save the `output_df` to a CSV file:

```
output_df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

`output.csv` file:

```
user.0,active,NOCHANGE
user.1,active,Disabled in ABC
user.2,active,NOCHANGE
user.5,active,Disabled in ABC
user.7,active,Does not exist in ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the csv module by first reading ABC into a dict, keying the status to uid:

```py
import csv

abc_status_map: dict[str, str] = {}

with open("abc.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # discard header

    for row in reader:
        abc_status_map[row[0]] = row[1]
```

abc_status_map looks like:

```py
{
    "user.0": "active",
    "user.1": "Disabled",
    "user.2": "active",
    "user.3": "Disabled",
    "user.4": "active",
    "user.5": "Disabled",
    "user.6": "active",
    "user.8": "active",
}
```

Your example output doesn't cover the case where something is Disabled in XYZ but active in ABC.  I went ahead and coded for that possibility:

```py
def get_abc_status(uid: str, xyz_status: str) -> str:
    abc_status = abc_status_map.get(uid)

    if abc_status is None:
        return "Does not exist in ABC"

    if abc_status == xyz_status:
        return "NOCHANGE"

    if xyz_status == "active":
        return "Disabled in ABC"

    return "Enabled in ABC"
```

and modified the XYZ CSV to test it:

```
| uid    | status   |
|--------|----------|
| user.0 | active   |
| user.1 | active   |
| user.2 | Disabled |  ← let's see what happens
| user.5 | active   |
| user.7 | active   |
```

Create a list of final rows, to append the computed rows to.  Intialize it with the output header:

```py
final_rows = [["uid", "status", "abc_status"]]
```

Then read XYZ, comparing statuses, appending the computed final rows, and finally writing the output:

```py
with open("xyz.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)

    for row in reader:
        uid = row[0]
        xyz_status = row[1]
        abc_status = get_abc_status(uid, xyz_status)

        final_rows.append([uid, xyz_status, abc_status])


with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(final_rows)
```

That gives me:

```
| uid    | status   | abc_status            |
| ------ | -------- | --------------------- |
| user.0 | active   | NOCHANGE              |
| user.1 | active   | Disabled in ABC       |
| user.2 | Disabled | Enabled in ABC        |  ← looks correct
| user.5 | active   | Disabled in ABC       |
| user.7 | active   | Does not exist in ABC |
```

Comment: Thank you very much Zach Young. 

This helps a lot. let me extend this to compare both ways.

Comment: This solution works well. Compared .5M account in 30 secs  :)